# How do I know which is ground and power in Piezo?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, pins, piezo

I have a piezoelectric sensor. Both pins are the same length. I have one like this: [Piezo picture](https://cdn.solarbotics.com/products/photos/93c51bd69dcc15a0f60bb6bb4c96d4df/lrg/17855-dscn3894.JPG). On the Piezo it's written *muRata* and *01P*. How do I know which do I send to the digital pins and which to the ground? I have an Arduino Uno.

Answer (score 2):

On the one I have, the shorter pin is ground. I discovered that empirically - a scientific word for "I tried it the wrong way round the first time but the magic smoke stayed inside." Afterwards I inspected it more carefully, I found a '+' embossed in the top surface nearer one side. :-o

Answer (score 1):

If you're using just one or sound quality doesn't matter: it doesn't matter.

Otherwise you need to figure it out with a scope like [this](http://service.toptica.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=7):

- Connect both poles of the connector of the PZT to an oscilloscope (time base approx. 50ms/div, y-axis 200mV/div).
- Slightly tap the head of the PZT with your finger. As a result you should get a voltage pulse on the oscilloscope.
- Positive Amplitude  -> + pole of the piezo is connected to the inner conductor of the oscilloscope BNC connector.
- Negative Amplitude -> + pole of the piezo is connected to the outer conductor of the oscilloscope BNC connector.

Comment: Please edit your answer and copy in the (smallish) amount of information from the linked site. StackExchange frowns on link-only answers in case the link goes dead. If you copy the information into your answer it then stands on its own.

Comment: @NickGammon Done!